Aggregate cell values in Pandastable
I have a dataframe being displayed in a TKinter GUI as a table using pandastable. I would like to select multiple numerical cells and have a label at the bottom which aggregates (sums) the selected values. Similar to how it works in Excel.
I looked at the documentation but can't figure out whether this is possible:
https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pandastable/core.html
A challenge is getting the select values. Can someone please help?
For example:
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class MainClass(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        self.main.geometry('600x400+200+100')
        self.main.title('TEST')
        f = Frame(self.main)
        f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        df = TableModel.getSampleData()

        names = list(df.columns)
        pt = Table(f, dataframe=df, showtoolbar=0, showstatusbar=0)
        pt.show()

app = MainClass()
app.mainloop()

